# How to prittyfy HTML and output files in same directory as exiting directory

Tags: javascript, gulp

Hey guys i basically work as a junior front End developer and recently started using gulp ,Now i get alot of HTML files from other senior developers that have code thats not very well formatted or has too much white space and bad indents , so thing like the below:

```
<div id="preloader">

        <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>

    </div>

    <div id="nav-anchor"></div>



    <div class="top-navbar-fixed">

        <nav class="sibling-website-nav">

            <ul>

                <li><a href="">Accounting</a></li><li class="active"><a href="">Training</a></li>

                <!-- <li><a href="">Recruitment</a></li> -->

            </ul>

        </nav>
```

See how much unnessasary whitespace is in there ., now if i use gulp these is this plugin **[HERE](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-prettify)**, Which can be used as following:

var prettify = require('gulp-html-prettify');

```
gulp.task('templates', function() {
  gulp.src('./lib/*.html')
    .pipe(prettify({indent_char: ' ', indent_size: 2}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
});
```

Now the problem is this does the job but the files are outputed in a differnet directory , what i want is not for new files to be created , but the existing files to be formatted in the directory they are itself , so how would i go about doing this in gulp then ?

Comment: Well, to start, you're piping the output to the directory `/dist`, and not `/lib`.

Comment: @bjskistad i realised that yes ... but is the code formatting the exiting files or creting new ones ? i am afraid that if its creating new ones then something might get badly screwed up !

Comment: Your task is getting the file data (`gulp.src()`), prettifying the data (`.pip(prettify())`), and then outputting to a file with the same name in a directory you specify (`gulp.dest()`). The original file is not changed by the prettifying. If you output to the original location as @bjskistad recommends (and it does sound like this is what you want), you will lose your original unformatted file and will have formatted files at `./lib/`. You can see this by testing on a backup copy of the project.

Comment: Yes, just copy the directory using `cp` (If you're on 'nix), as @henry recommends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it looks like you need to `pipe()` your result to the right directory.
Try this code

```
var prettify = require('gulp-html-prettify');

gulp.task('templates', function() {
  gulp.src('./lib/*.html')
    .pipe(prettify({indent_char: ' ', indent_size: 2}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./lib/'))
});
```